# Issue inserting-and-updating-related-models on Laravel 5 and Angular project

Tags: sql, angularjs, laravel, typescript

I am new on Laravel and I am stocked on this issue since 24hours now... I am on a AngularJS 1.5 with typscript for the front and Laravel 5 for the back and I have this error message: `{"message":"Undefined index: sector","status_code":500}` comming from the back...normally the front is ok but I'll post it anyway, here is the code (I only post the needed part of the code):

projectRepository.php:

```
 <?php
 namespace Modules\Project\Repositories;

 use DB;
 use Modules\Project\Entities\Project;
 use Modules\Sector\Entities\Sector;
 use Modules\Sector\Entities\SectorTranslation;

 class ProjectRepository
 {
    const technologiesStringSelect = "(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
  LOWER(technologies.label) SEPARATOR ' ')
                                    FROM project_technology
                                    INNER JOIN technologies ON technologies.id = project_technology.technology_id
                                    WHERE project_technology.project_id = projects.id)";

/**
 * Create or update a project.
 *
 * @param object $request
 * @param object $project
 *
 * @return null|object|static
 */
    public function createOrUpdate($request, $project = null)
    {
    // Create new project
    if (is_null($project))  {

        $params = $request->except([
            'screenshots',
            'project_file',
            'technologies',
        ]);
             ($params["sector"] = $project); 
            $s = Sector::create();
            SectorTranslation::create([
                'sector' => $s->id,
                'label' => $params["en"]["sector"],
                'locale' => 'en'
            ]);
            $s = Sector::create();
            SectorTranslation::create([
                'sector' => $s->id,
                'label' => $params["fr"]["sector"],
                'locale' => 'fr'
            ]);
            $params["sector"] = $s->id;


        // Create the project
        $project = Project::create($params);

        // Save technologies many-to-many
        $project->technologies()->attach($request->input('technologies'));

    } else { ...
```

project.form.ts:

```
  constructor(private $mdDialog: material.IDialogService,
            private dateFilter: angular.IFilterDate,
            private Project: ProjectService,
            private Technology: TechnologyService,
            private languages: ILanguage[]) {
    'ngInject';
    this.projectFile = {};
    this.screenshotFiles = [];
    this.screenshots = [];
}

save() {
    let project = new FormData();

    project.safeAppend('name', this.project.name);
    project.safeAppend('start_date', 
  this.dateFilter(this.project.start_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    project.safeAppend('end_date', 
  this.dateFilter(this.project.end_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    project.safeAppend('sector', this.project.sector);
    project.safeAppend('team_size', this.project.team_size);
```

project.form.component.html:

```
  <md-input-container md-no-float flex>
                <input type="string" ng-model="$ctrl.project[$ctrl.formLocale].sector" placeholder="{{ 'ACTIVITY_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}" flex>
                 <!--   <md-option ng-value="sector.id" ng-repeat="sector in $ctrl.sectors">{{ sector.label }}</md-option>
                    <md-option ng-value="-1">{{ 'OTHER' | translate }}
   </md-option>
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container> 
            <md-input-container ng-show="$ctrl.project.sector" md-no-float flex> 
                <label>{{ 'NEW_SECTOR' | translate }}</label> 
                <input ng-model="$ctrl.project[$ctrl.formLocale].newSectorName"> -->
            </md-input-container>
```

Comment: @georgeawg, when I did an php artisan route: list I see `GET|HEAD | client   |      | Modules\Client\Http\Controllers\ClientController@index | web(middleware)   ` and `GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure                                                | api,auth:api(middleware)`

Comment: Looks like the error is `$params["en"]["sector"]` or `$params["fr"]["sector"]`. We don't know what that array looks like, though..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for your help so if I follow you looks like I should, replace the sector's label coming from 
 the input send by the user `<input type="string"`, any ideas or code exemple how to realise it?